# Loading spinner image while php is executing using script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Hi i am trying to use script to display a loading bar while my php is executing. I learnt from this [website](http://article.onlinewebtool.com/showing-a-loading-gif-image-while-a-page-loads-using-javascript-and-css/) but when I did the exactly same thing, my loading bar still cannot display, any idea why?

```
<html>
   <head>

 <style type="text/css">
   div#content {
   display: none;
  }

div#loading {
   top: 200 px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 160px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url(img/142.gif) no-repeat;
  cursor: wait;
 }
</style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function preloader(){
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
    }//preloader
    window.onload = preloader;
</script>

<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="content" >

<?php

sleep(10);
echo 'This content has been loaded via an AJAX request';

?>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: style="display: none;">

Comment: what do you mean? @Kannan

Comment: Your id **loading** is **display:none**

Comment: I delete that, still not working.<div id="loading"></div> @Kannan

Comment: `echo 'This content has been loaded via an AJAX request';` – you’re lying, it isn’t … and most likely therefor this does not work as intended, because stuff like output buffering etc. will come in the way – the browser waits until he has received the complete resource before displaying anything. If you want a loading animation for an AJAX request, then _make_ an actual AJAX request to test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just run this code in any browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ob_end_clean();
set_time_limit(0);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div#content {
                display: none;
            }
            img#loading {
                top: 200 px;
                margin: auto;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1000;
                width: 500px;
                height: 24px;
                cursor: wait;
                height: 500px
            }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            echo str_repeat(' ', 1024 * 64); // this is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
            if ($i == 1)
                echo '<img id="loading" src="img/142.gif" />';
        }
        ?>
        <div id="content" style="display: block;">
            <?php
            sleep(5);
            echo 'This content has been loaded via an AJAX request';
            ?>
            <br>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function preloader() {
                document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
            }//preloader
            window.onload = preloader;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

if you have acces to php.ini set following configuration in your php.ini and remove 
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);  @ini_set('implicit_flush', 1); from begining

```
output_buffering = Off
implicit_flush = on
output_compression = Off
```

If your are curious about output buffering [click here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

sleep(1000);//increase sleep time
echo 'This content has been loaded via an AJAX request';

?>
```

and remove `style="display: none;"`